# Library to write an odf file from a C program

Tags: c, document, openoffice.org

Does anyone know of a library that will allow me to write an odt (Open Document Format, i.e. OpenOffice compatible) file from a C program?

Comment: It's EASY to tell what is being asked here - closing this question is silly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ODT/ODF is basically zipped XML, so any XML library will do. You'll need to know the specification though if you're going to write a new ODT file from scratch. It's much easier to unpack an existing ODT and insert data into contained the content.xml file.

See [OASIS OpenDocument Essentials](http://books.evc-cit.info/books/odbook/book.html) (especially the "The Virtues of Cheating" paragraph)